# Hoover zoom effect with multiple images and keep image dimension

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to make a hover zoom effect with multiple images:

- images are centered on the page
- keep dimensions while zooming in
- image width is set inline at img tag

Here is what I tried so far:

```css
.img-zoom {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
.img-zoom img {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.04);
-ms-transform: scale(1.04);
transform: scale(1.04);
-webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
transition: 0.4s ease;
margin: 0px 20px;
}
.img-zoom img:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.21);
-ms-transform: scale(1.21);
transform: scale(1.21);
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;padding: 5px;">
    <div class="img-zoom">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/210" width="300" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/210" width="300"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

...but the images are extending on mouse hover.

Comment: What do you mean by "...but the images are extending on mouse hover."? Can you elaborate?

Comment: why you don't put your images in divs with fixed size?

Comment: I am trying to achieve this effect: https://www.philowen.co/blog/image-zoom-hover-pure-css/ - but with multiple images in a DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the images to zoom in without their width/height changing. I've modified your HTML a bit and placed the inline `width` parameter on the `.img-zoom` element. I think this accomplishes what you need.

```css
.img-zoom {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-zoom img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* center zoom */
}
.img-zoom img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.21);
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 5px; text-align: center;">
  <div class="img-zoom" style="width: 300px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/210" />
  </div>
  <div class="img-zoom" style="width: 300px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/210"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, unless that the images are not side by side. I edited your code, I hope I did it the right way, let me know what you think.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks! My bad for thinking you wanted the images stacked top-to-bottom; I only saw your snippet in the tiny window where they laid out that way and assumed it was what you wanted.